# Update through stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures, exception, sql-update

I have three tables `Table1`, `Table2`, `Table3`. I've three columns in `Table1`-> `Tier1`, `Tier2` and `Flag` which **`may or may not be null`** . I'm joining these tables based on common columns and `updating` these three columns.

My code is as follow:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpUpdateTable]
AS     
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     BEGIN TRANSACTION;
     BEGIN TRY    

        UPDATE Table1  
        SET Tier_1 = tbl3.T1, Modify_Date = SYSDATETIME()
        FROM Table1 tbl1
        JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.CommonColumn1 = tbl2.CommonColumn1
        JOIN Table3 tbl3 ON tbl2.CommonColumn2 = tbl3.CommonColumn2
        WHERE tbl1.BrandName = 'Dell' AND 
        (tbl3.T1 IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.Tier_1 IS NULL OR tbl1.Tier_1 <>  tbl3.T1);

        UPDATE Table1  
        SET Tier_2 = tbl3.T2, Modify_Date = SYSDATETIME()
        FROM Table1 tbl1
        JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.CommonColumn1 = tbl2.CommonColumn1
        JOIN Table3 tbl3 ON tbl2.CommonColumn2 = tbl3.CommonColumn2
        WHERE tbl1.BrandName = 'Dell' AND 
        (tbl3.T2 IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.Tier_2 IS NULL OR tbl1.Tier_2 <>  tbl3.T2);


        UPDATE Table1  
        SET Flag = tbl3.Flag, Modify_Date = SYSDATETIME()
        FROM Table1 tbl1
        JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.CommonColumn1 = tbl2.CommonColumn1
        JOIN Table3 tbl3 ON tbl2.CommonColumn2 = tbl3.CommonColumn2
        WHERE tbl1.BrandName = 'Dell' AND 
        (tbl3.Flag IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.Flag IS NULL OR tbl1.Flag <> tbl3.Flag);

   END TRY 
   BEGIN CATCH
         IF @@TRANSCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN;        
   END CATCH

   IF @@TRANSCOUNT > 0
      COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Well my code is updating columns one by one. My concern is rather `hitting database` for updating each column, Is there any way we can do this using single update query?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s : Thanks for this info, corrected this. But that's just for naming. I've changed the actual code which I can't directly paste it here.

Comment: Not that it will help your performance, but you may get more constructive answers: It's nearly impossible to tell what is going on at a glance, and feels too much like work. Would it be possible to provide more meaningful names to `Table1` through `Table3`? Try forgetting that you just wrote it, and read your `where` clauses with repeated `tblx.Flag` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 BEGIN TRY    

    UPDATE Table1  
        SET Modify_Date = SYSDATETIME(),
            Tier_1 = CASE WHEN (tbl3.T1 IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.Tier_1 IS NULL OR tbl1.Tier_1 <>  tbl3.T1) THEN
                        tbl3.T1
                     ELSE 
                        Tier_1 
                     END,
            Tier_2 = CASE WHEN (tbl3.T2 IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.Tier_2 IS NULL OR tbl1.Tier_2 <>  tbl3.T2) THEN
                        tbl3.T2
                     ELSE 
                        Tier_2
                     END,
            Flag = CASE WHEN (tbl3.Flag IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.Flag IS NULL OR tbl1.Flag <> tbl3.Flag) THEN
                        tbl3.Flag
                     ELSE
                        Flag
                     END
    FROM Table1 tbl1
    JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.CommonColumn1 = tbl2.CommonColumn1
    JOIN Table3 tbl3 ON tbl2.CommonColumn2 = tbl3.CommonColumn2
    WHERE tbl1.BrandName = 'Dell' 
    AND 
    (
        (tbl3.T1 IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.Tier_1 IS NULL OR tbl1.Tier_1 <>  tbl3.T1)
        OR 
        (tbl3.T2 IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.Tier_2 IS NULL OR tbl1.Tier_2 <>  tbl3.T2)
        OR
        (tbl3.Flag IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.Flag IS NULL OR tbl1.Flag <> tbl3.Flag)
    )
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    --code to catch exception
END CATCH
```

Comment: @TabAlleman correct, I didn't notice that the updates was for different columns. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

```
with x as (
    select tbl1.tier_1 tbl1_tier_1, tbl1.tier_2 tbl1_tier_2, tbl1.flag tbl1_flag, tbl3.t1, tbl3.t2, tbl3.flag
    from table1 tbl1
    join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.commoncolumn1 = tbl2.commoncolumn1
    join table3 tbl3 on tbl2.commoncolumn2 = tbl3.commoncolumn2
    where tbl1.brandname = 'Dell' 
)
update x 
set
    tbl1_tier_1 = isnull(tbl1_tier_1, t1),
    tbl1_tier_2 = isnull(tbl1_tier_2, t2),
    tbl1_tier_3 = isnull(tbl1_tier_3, t3),
    modify_date = sysdatetime()
```

It will update a value in Table1 only if it's NULL, otherwise it will leave the existing value.

Comment: Hi dean thanks for this code. Your code is only taking the scenario of NULL, what if column value is different and I want to update with the value we're fetching? I want to include this scenario as well.